# Flickering/rendering issue with -webkit-transform

Tags: css, webkit, css-transforms

I'm experiencing a strange issue with `-webkit-transform`. If I use `perspective` and `rotateX` to make an element "flip up", if the element is tall enough, it flickers or does not render at all past a certain angle.

I've set up a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLQjP/1/) which illustrates the problem. Move the mouse left and right to rotate the rectangle.

- When the element is 400px tall, everything seems to work fine.
- Click on "4000" to make the element 4000px tall. The **text stops updating** in a certain range and **rendering is flickery**.
- Click on "40000" to make the element 40000px tall. It renders fine at small angles, but **disappears entirely at about 80 degrees**.

What's going on here? Is there a workaround or should I be filing a WebKit bug?

(Note: I see this behavior in both Safari and Chrome on OS X.)

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome on Windows, unless I'm using the fiddle wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this code is in the `CSS3` `perspective` property. When the element is 4000px in height or more is disappears when it gets nearer the screen, because it is only 500px away (defined with the `perspective` property.

There, if the element is higher, the element should be further away.

I made some if-statements to get the different perspectives depending on the elements height:

```
if (document.getElementById("m2").offsetHeight == 400) {
    document.getElementById("m2").style.webkitTransform = "perspective(500) rotateX(" + (e.clientX / 5) + "deg)";
}

if (document.getElementById("m2").offsetHeight == 4000) {
    document.getElementById("m2").style.webkitTransform = "perspective(5000) rotateX(" + (e.clientX / 5) + "deg)";
}

if (document.getElementById("m2").offsetHeight == 40000) {
    document.getElementById("m2").style.webkitTransform = "perspective(50000) rotateX(" + (e.clientX / 5) + "deg)";
}
```

Comment: I'll test this more later, but with a quick test it seems still a little flickery (though not nearly as bad!). But, of course, this greatly changes the visual effect. Is there a way to do something similar without changing the perceived perspective?

Comment: When is it flickering? Is it when the `#m2` is large and its angle gets near 90 deg?

Comment: Yeah. [Here's a video](http://cl.ly/1V3e1x1i201K1L3Z3h3C) that shows what I'm seeing — I recorded both the original version and your version.

Comment: Hmm seems to be a problem in Safari only. It's flickering in my Safari aswell, but not in Chrome. I will take a look it a bit later.